# No breadcrumb on front page

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I've a Drupal 8 (8.5.4) site  which is using a custom created on top of Bootstrap Barrio. I'm using Easy Breadcrumbs module. Here is the configuration I used.

1. Easy Breadcrumb settings

[image]

2. The default homepage in /admin/config/system/site-information is set as node.
3. Nothing is added in "No Results Behavior" for the view "FrontPage"

The problem is when I go to http://localhost (place where my site is hosted), the breadcrumbs are not rendered. I'm expecting it to show the text "Home" in the breadcrumb region, as configured in Easy Breadcrumb settings. However on rest of the pages, the breadcrumb shows the breadcrumb for the page preceded by Home.

Comment: In which theme you are placing the block?

Comment: Check if the setting "Hide link to home page if it's the only breadcrumb item" is unchecked.

Comment: @AjayReddy I created a custom theme which is based on "Bootstrap Barrio'

Comment: @Martin Borugadda Have you placed the block in right theme? And also check `Administration theme`. Is it your custom theme or Drupal default theme.

Comment: Try easy breadcrumbs on a fresh D8 installation.
I had missing breadcrumbs and it turned out to be some mess in the configuration yaml, but I can't remember which one.